# Delete answered negative voted question

Tags: support, questions, specific-question, down-votes

This is the concerned [question](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/45088/longest-simple-path-in-a-complete-graph).

The question has a negative score. 
So, it implies that the question is not  valuable/worthy of being on the site [ I obviously disagree - moreover I got the answer too].

I don't like the negative score and would like to delete the question but if the question is valuable to the site then it shouldn't be negatively voted.

Comment: To me, the question reads more or less as a problem dump. In other words, the asker is not specifying what exactly the problem is. Moreover, the asker indicates no effort (what was tried, why that didn't work?) But even so, maybe you are reading too much into a single downvote, especially given that it is the only vote the question has. Maybe someone else likes it, and upvotes it? My guess is that the downvote could disappear if the question did show research effort.

Comment: @Juho I did actually post an answer showing my research/try and then deleted it. I have undeleted it, you can check it yourself.

Comment: @Juho also if the question is bad then why am I not allowed to remove it?

Comment: Questions can be (and should be) improved through edits. I think this is also definitely the case here. We don't want to remove questions that are useful (or have good potential to be useful) for other people. Also, we don't want to take away from the people that took the time to answer a question that was upvoted (i.e. let them have the reputation points).

Comment: I can try improving the question, just a moment :-)

Comment: Okay. But I actually fail to see any scope of improvement[didn't read the above comment]. Anyway, let it be. It's just that a negative score is irritating to my eyes.

Comment: OK, I think it's better now. Feel absolutely free to edit what I did. But you should get the basic idea I had in mind: the question *does* show definite research effort now. I think it definitely doesn't deserve a downvote anymore. Would you agree it's better? (You can probably delete your old answer now too -- by the way I was able to see it even when it was deleted. I used the information from that to edit the original question).

Comment: Your initial question was *bad*, so it's no surprise it gets downvotes. And *of course* the system prevents you from deleting just to clean up your score *after people spend time on helping you*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I feel like you are reading too much into a single downvote. Still, edits can (and should) happen to improve question quality. I believe the downvote in this case was because the question reads like a problem dump. That is, it does not show research effort (what was tried, what didn't work, where exactly is the problem).

The reason the system does not allow deletion of downvoted questions is (partly) due to the fact that questions can be improved ("salvaged"). I tried my best to edit the question; I believe it is only a matter of time the question gets upvotes and/or the downvote disappears.

Comment: Nice edit. I need to learn a lot :/

Comment: @AtulGangwar No worries, we all have to start from something :-) Glad it was of help!

Comment: Thanks for your edit to that question, Juho.